# Scrolling in AngularJS from the controller is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I just want to scroll to top.

I have tried this:

$window.scrollTo(0, 0);

That didn't work, neither did window.scrollTo(0,0). Then I tried:

$location.hash('top'); //with  in the view

$anchorScroll();

That didn't work either.
I have seen some custom angular modules for scrolling, but I wouldn't really like to use even more code for something so simple which should be working anyway. Perhaps there is something wrong with my controller/view?

Here is my controller:

```
.controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $window, $http, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $anchorScroll, $rootScope, $location, $compile) {

var controller = this;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        if (toState.name == 'app.page') {
            if(fromState.name != 'app.page2')
                controller.init();
        }
    });

this.init = function () { 
    $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Logging in',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 1
    });

    $window.scrollTo(0, 0); //should it be here?
    window.scrollTo(0, 0); //not working at all??

    .....


}


......
```

Template:

```
<style>
    ...
</style>

<ion-view view-title="something" ng-init="pgctrl.init()">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-calm" ng-click="pgctrl.init()">
            New
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
        ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

App.js  in .config:

```
  .state('app.page', {
      url: '/page',
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
              controller: 'PageCtrl as pgctrl'
          }
      }
  })
```

Comment: How about using `stateChangeSuccess` for the window scrolling event so that it will fire when the transition is done?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't against using jQuery(which you are pretty much using anyways), you could try to do this.

**In this.init**

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop: $('.view').offset().top}, "slow");
```

**Template**

```
<ion-view view-title="something" class="view" ng-init="pgctrl.init()">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-calm" ng-click="pgctrl.init()">
            New
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
        ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution. I figured out that since I have this ion-nav-buttons at the top any "scroll to top" would think that we are there already, hence why it wouldn't work. After searching for a way to make ionic do the scrolling, I found this:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop(true); //where true says whether to animate it
```

That did the work. Thanks also to the guys who helped solve this!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 400);
```

You can simply use this.400 is the time delay in ms. 0px is the vertical scroll position.